# confused with the result of df.loc['column'].apply(pd.Series)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I had a column in a data frame `df` as
`RecentDelays': [[23, 47], [], [24, 43, 87], [13], [67, 32]]`.

when I do `df['RecentDelays'].apply(pd.Series)`  I get

```
Index  0     1       2  
0   23.0    47.0    
1           
2   24.0    43.0    87.0  
3   13.0        
4   67.0    32.0
```

I am confused here because I am expecting the `df` to be filled column wise when Series is applied for each list in the column of `df`
In simple words I am expecting

```
Index 0   1   2   3   4  
0     23     24   13  67  
1     47     43       87  
2            87
```

Comment: Did you just want to share your confusion with us, or what is your question?

Comment: I just want to know how is the result the way it is because I think pd.Series creates a DataFrame column wise but why am I getting row-wise DataFrame,  I mean row-wise DataFrames are created with additions of rows and column-wise DataFrames are created with additions of coumns

Comment: Try `.transpose()`